# Swift iOS App UIPickerView how to know when animation is done?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I have a "casino machine" in my iOS app, with 3 `UIPickerView` objects.

When my button is pressed, this function starts in each picker (I created my own `UIPickerView` class picker):

```
func selectRandomRow()
{
    // Aller à la ligne numéro randomNumber
    let randomRow = FDUtils.shared.random(min: 1, max: self.pickerDataSize - 2)

    if (self.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) != 0)
    {
        goToRow(valueToGo: randomRow)
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectRow(randomRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
}
```

`goToRow` function is:

```
func goToRow(valueToGo: Int)
{
    FDUtils.shared.delay(0.1, closure:
    {
        let currentRow = self.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

        if (currentRow > valueToGo)
        {
            self.selectRow(currentRow - 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            self.goToRow(valueToGo: valueToGo)
        }
        else if (currentRow < valueToGo)
        {
            self.selectRow(currentRow + 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            self.goToRow(valueToGo: valueToGo)
        }
        else if (currentRow == valueToGo)
        {
            print("currentRow == valueToGo")
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.delegateGame.didRowSelected()
        }
    })
}
```

My FDUtils.shared.delay function is :

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->())
{
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
```

When each picker is done (I consider done when `delegateGame.didRowSelected()` is called) I have a function that shows a notification to the user. The problem is, if animation is enabled, the delegate call the function `didRowSelected` *before* animation is done.

So I'm displaying the notification before the last picker finished scrolling.

How can I know what is the animation's duration of a UIPickerView? (and then set a delay before I call `didRowSelected`, but I'm not sure that a clean solution) or how can I call `didRowSelected` after animation is done?

Comment: You probably should use the `UIPickerViewDelegate`  protocol to detect value changes. But I'm not sure if the change event fires when you programmatically set the picker value.

Comment: I tried, that's doesn't work because as you guessed didSelectRow isn't fired when you set a value programmatically :(